# R Shiny renderDataTable options

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

Is there a comprehensive list of option names (and hopefully descriptions) that can be passed to the `options` argument of `renderDataTable()` in Shiny?

The option names I've seen used in examples online don't seem to map to the option names on the DataTables options docs (http://datatables.net/reference/option). For example, the `pageLength` options in DataTables is called `iDisplayLength` in Shiny.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shiny has upgraded DataTables from 1.9.x to 1.10.x since **shiny** 0.10.2, and you can use the options listed at http://datatables.net/reference/option/ if your **shiny** version is higher than 0.10.2.

Comment: Thank you, it's good to know why the option names weren't matching! This is helpful.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I realize the commands shown here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html do work now that I updated `shiny`.

Answer (score 0):

If this setting is located in a separate file that is sourced by your application (for example: `my_app.R` sources `my_module.R` where the `datatable` is created/defined), then you may need to source the separate file manually (or remove the previous sourced versions from the workspace) to get changes in this setting to show up.

For some reason, even if `my_app.R` sources `my_module.R` on run time this setting (and other options like it) are not always picked up.

Manual sourcing of the file has not been necessary for me when the `datatable` is created in `my_app.R`, `ui.R` or `server.R`.